# Add wait time in dart

Tags: dart

How can I add a wait time in dart/flutter.
I have two blocks of code to be executed after an `if else statement`.
I want to add some time between them because the first one got a message to display to the user.

```
if(test==true){
 print("Hello"};
 //wait time added here 
 print("This hello after 5 secondes");
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5), () => print('This hello after 5 seconds'));
```

Answer (score 3):

There is any number of ways to do it, depending on how you want it to work, and whether your function is already asynchronous.

In general, you cannot insert a delay into a function which isn't asynchronous, not without blocking everything else.

- If you don't want anything to happen in-between, and don't mind blocking,
  you can use [sleep](https://api.dart.dev/be/137752/dart-io/sleep.html)
  from `dart:io`

  ```dart
  sleep(const Duration(seconds: 5));
  ```

  or if you are on the web, and don't have `dart:io`, you can busy-wait:

  ```dart
  var sw = Stopwatch()..start();
  while (sw.elapsedMilliseconds < 5000) {}
  ```

  Both block any other computation from happening in the same isolate.
  The latter also spends a lot of CPU power doing it.
- If your don't want to block (you usually don't), and your function
  is already asynchronous (returns a future, is marked `async`),
  you can easily insert a non-blocking pause:

  ```dart
  // before the pause
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));
  // rest of function
  ```

  Consider *making* your function asynchronous if it isn't already.
- If you don't want to block, but your function is not asynchronous,
  then you need to start an asynchronous operation, and put the rest
  of your function into that, so that it will execute later.
  Then your function *returns* (synchronously), so no-one will be able
  to wait for the delayed part to happen.
  You can use any of:

  ```dart
  Timer(const Duration(seconds: 5), () {
    // rest of function.
  });
  ```

  or

  ```
  unawaited(Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5), () {
    // rest of function.
  }));
  ```

  or even introduce a local `async` function

  ```dart
  unawaited(() async {
     await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));
     // rest of function.
  }());
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Below is an example to Future.delayed method :

```
Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1,milliseconds: 600), () {

// Here you can write your code
  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Future.delayed` to acheive that.

```
if(test==true){
   print("Hello");
  Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5), () {
    print("This hello after 5 secondes");
  });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it also possible to use `Timer` as well:

```
Timer(Duration(seconds: 5), () => print("This hello after 5 seconds"));
```